# User Parameters aren't sent with GA4 Event Configured in GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've encountered a problem I've never seen before and don't know where to look anymore. I've configured user parameters in my GA4 Event Tag:

[image]

When debugging the event, I can clearly see that the parameters are recognised by GTM and are in fact there:
[image]

But when checking the network for the google analytics call, I discovered that the user properties aren't found in the final url:

```
Busy: https://data.sendpulse.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-46NQ594GKJ>m=2re1c0&_p=179854930&sr=1920x1080&_dbg=1&ul=en-gb&cid=1181847091.1636366263&_s=2&dl=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.sendpulse.com%2Fmembers%2Femailservice%2Ftasks%2Fview%2Fid%2F127442%2Fr%2F1642607412&dr=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.sendpulse.com%2Femailservice%2Ftasks%2Fadd%2Fcampaign%2F2e83b96b%2Freview%2F&dt=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%2F%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%2F%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8&uid=7860071&sid=1642607121&sct=103&seg=1&en=dynamic_experiment&_et=29&ep.transport=beacon&ep.debug_mode=true&ep.exp=dynamic_plan_upgrade.0&richsstsse
```

Since the gtm debugger shows everything is ok I don't even know where to look. Any help here would be highly appreciated. (BTW, exact same parameters are sent with pageviews without any problems)

Answer (score 0):

Check GA4 DebugView. Since I have tried to replicate your case I can see my user property in DebugView.

[GA4 DebugView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd4N7.png)

[GTM setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b65Bz.png)

Comment: Hi! My understanding is there won't be any user properties in debug view since they are not passed to google analytics. I imagine if they are not present in the url parameters, there won't be anything to display. At this point I'm starting to believe there might be some conflict with the configuration tag which also has user properties.

Comment: They need to present in DebugView in order to get proceed in GA4 interface. Try to do some testing - delete your user properties in configuration tag and keep them in your event tag. There is also limitation for user properties, 25 per property. When you start to see them in your DebugView you need to register them in Configure tab (otherwise you won't be able to see in GA4 interface). Go to Configure -> Custom Definitions -> Create new (user scoped)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I'm checking the raw data in BigQuery and while I haven't registered any properties in the GA4 interface, I can still see them in the raw data. I'll try your suggestion and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that my user properties are passed on the network call and can be seen directly in the query string.  I would completely double check your setup and potentially take another look at the network activity. Also, try making sure you have debug inside the GA4 interface enabled in the same browser. It shouldn't cause or limit the network activity but might be another way to verify.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot send a user property name with an event,
when that user property has formerly been sent with the GA4 configuration tag itself.